# Calculate the percentage of users with a facebook cookie?

Tags: facebook, session, cookies, fbml

I'm trying to determine if there is a way that I can count percentage of users visiting our website that already have a facebook cookie on their browser.

I'm trying to determine how strongly we should commit to integrating facebook's social features into our website, and wanted to understand the reach of facebook in our audience.

Comment: I'm just going to point out I'm not 100% sure this is even possible; please let me know if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) you could figure out how many people are logged into facebook when they're on your site. You would just check to see how many people have `response.status === 'not_authorized'`.

Comment: Does this require them to be authorized into an app of ours first? I'm just looking to see if they're actually facebook users.

Comment: No, read the documentation on the page. response.status === 'not_authorized' would tell you that the user is logged into facebook, but hasn't authorized your app, which is what you want to know.